# Angular error TypeError: <service-name> is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, service

I'm coding a basic Login App. I have

./js/app.js

```js
'use strict';

var drfmApp = angular.module('drfmApp', [
    'ngRoute','drfmControllers'
]);
```

./js/controllers/LoginController.js

```js
'use strict';

var drfmControllers = angular.module('drfmControllers', []);


drfmControllers.controller('LoginController', ['$scope','$location',

    function($scope,LoginService) {

        $scope.login = function () {

          console.log($scope.user.username);
          LoginService.login();
        }
    }
]);
```

./js/services/LoginService.js

```js
'use strict';

drfmApp.factory('LoginService',function(){

    return {
        login:function(){
            console.log("enter function login service");
        },
        logout:function(){
            console.log("enter functuon logout service");
        }
    }
});
```

And finally the partial View HTML

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">

            <header>Wellcome, {{user.username}}</header>

            <blockquote>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.
                </p> <small>Someone famous <cite>Source Title</cite></small>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="form" ng-submit="login()" >
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                        Username
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                        Password
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">

                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" /> Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

                        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                        <a href="#/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I always have this error

**TypeError: login is not a function**

when click on "Login" Button of the page.

Comment: Basic debugging would lead you to what everyone points out, you made no effort whatsoever to solve this

Answer (score 2):

> In array-like dependency injection, items in `array` are mapped to the `arguments` of the controller function.

Try this:

```js
drfmControllers.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', 'LoginService',
  function($scope, LoginService) {//can be used as `function(s, l)`
    $scope.login = function() {
      console.log($scope.user.username);
      LoginService.login();
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stackoverflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You're injecting $scope and $location, not your login service. In order to use it you have to inject it first.

Change it to this:

```
drfmControllers.controller('LoginController', ['$scope','LoginService', function($scope, LoginService) {
        $scope.login = function () {
          console.log($scope.user.username);
          LoginService.login();
        }
    }
]);
```